# Why Node js app stops randomly at certain external api call for one minute and then moves on?

Tags: javascript, api, performance, backend, riot-games-api

I have an fastify server that uses riot external api and everything was working perfectly, until few days ago (I wasn't even trouching the code, all I did were some fixes to features completely unrelated to those causing problems, few days before the problem appeared).

Functions that would before take about 3 minutes, take 16 now. Overall the performance dropped down drastically.

I managed to localize the problem and it is as following. While normally call to external riot api takes around 0.2-0.5s (max), now from time to time the app freezes/stops? at one of the calls and it is always for exactly one minute. I use perf_hooks to made measurements and it show clearly that if the call takes more than it normally should, the wait is for 1 minute.

```
 performance.mark('example-start');

        const matchDataResponse = await axios.get(
          `https://europe.api.riotgames.com/tft/match/v1/matches/${matchId}`
        );
        performance.mark('example-end');
        if (
          performance.measure('example', 'example-start', 'example-end')
            .duration > 5000
        ) {
          console.log(
            performance.measure('example', 'example-start', 'example-end')
              .duration
          );
        }
```

[long calls always take a minute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPccR.png)
I tried ton of things, including looking at cpu usage, memory usage, limit-rates on external api, uploading dependencies, node and I'm completely stuck and still unsure ensure whether it is my fault or sth is wrong on Riot's side (I cannot find any informations about their api performance issues).

Any ideas or insight would be very helpful, because I do not know whether to keep digging or just hope it is not mine problem

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/RiotGames/developer-relations/issues/707

Answer (score 2):

This is a currently known issue with the Riot Games API you are using.
https://github.com/RiotGames/developer-relations/issues/707